# C++ vector sort gives 0 as output

Tags: c++

I'm trying to sort the contents of the vector in ascending order I know how to do that but when I'm tring it I'm getting output as 0.I tried sorting in descending order and I'm getting the correct answer in that case.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;
class Edge {
 public:
  int node1;
  int node2;
  int edge_weight;
  
  Edge()   
  {}

  Edge(int n1,int n2,int w)   
  {
       node1=n1;
       node2=n2;
       edge_weight=w;   
   } 
};

bool mycompare(Edge e1,Edge e2) 
{   
  return e1.edge_weight<e2.edge_weight; 
}

int main() 
{   
  int V, E;   
  cin >> V >> E;   
  vector<Edge> v(E);   
  int *parent=new int[V];
  for(int i=0;i<V;i++)   
  {
    parent[i]=i;   
  }   
  
  int count=0;  
  for(int i=0;i<E;i++)
  {
    int s1,s2,weight;
    cin>>s1>>s2>>weight;
    Edge e(s1,s2,weight);
      
    v.push_back(e);
  }     
  
  sort(v.begin(),v.end(),mycompare);    
  for(int i=0;i<E;i++)
  {
    cout<<v[i].node1<<" "<<v[i].node2<<" "<<v[i].edge_weight<<endl;
  }   
  return 0; 
}
```

**Input:**

> 4 4
>
> 0 1 3
>
> 0 3 5
>
> 1 2 1
>
> 2 3 8

**Output in case of descending order:**

> 2 3 8
>
> 0 3 5
>
> 0 1 3
>
> 1 2 1

**Output in case of ascending order:**

> 0 0 0
>
> 0 0 0
>
> 0 0 0
>
> 0 0 0

Here, the output in case of descending order is correct but for ascending
I'm getting 0 as the value for all the nodes.

Comment: "2 3 8" would be [ascending](http://www.mathsteacher.com.au/year7/ch02_power/06_asc/asc.htm) order, *not* descending.

Comment: @JesperJuhl `2 3 8` is the first object in descending order, `8 > 5 > 3 > 1`. The objects are sorted by the last value.

Answer (score 3):

`vector<Edge> v(E);` creates a vector with `E` elements, all `0`, then `v.push_back(e);` will add the new elements after the zero'd elements. So you have a vector with `2*E` elements, the first `E` are zero'd and the second `E` are the elements you want. If you sort them ascending, the zero'd elements come first.

Print them by iterating over the whole vector and you will see it:

```
for(const auto& i: v)
{
   cout<<i.node1<<" "<< i.node2<<" "<< i.edge_weight<<endl;
}
```

To solve your problem just don't create a vector with `E` elements, but an empty one: `vector<Edge> v;`.

You can use `v.reserve(E);` to allocate memory for `E` elements, if you want to increase the performance.

Comment: Alternatively, you can leave the default construction of E `Edge`s, and `v[i] = Edge(s1,s2,weight);` in the loop

Comment: @Caleth or `v.emplace_back(s1,s2,weight);` to avoid a copy of the `Edge` objects. It seems to be some kind of training, so I wanted to keep things simple.